# List input into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a problem set for class where I am given a csv file of text abbreviations for words and I'm asked to prompt the user for multiple abbreviations and its supposed to return the full text if the abbreviation is found, if not then it will return the original abbreviation.

I'm currently stuck on getting the user input list into the dictionary properly.

```
import csv

def CreateDictionary(i):            
    abbrv = i.lower()
    abbrv = i.split(' ')

    dictionary = {}
    fo = open('filename.csv')
    data = csv.reader(fo)
    for row in data:
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
    fo.close()

def main():
    user = input("abbreviations")       
    print(CreateDictionary(user))

main()
```

Comment: Your `print(CreateDictionary(user))` line will not print anything, as `CreateDictionary` does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def CreateDictionary(i):            
    abbrv = i.lower()
    abbrv = i.split(' ')

    dictionary = {}
    fo = open('filename.csv')
    data = csv.reader(fo)
    for row in data:
        if row[0] in abbrv: 
            yield (row[0],row[1])
    fo.close()

user = input("abbreviations")       
print(list(CreateDictionary(user)))
```

might do what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the values of the keys in dictionary to a list if they are present

```
import csv

def CreateDictionary(i):            
    abbrv = i.lower()
    abbrv = i.split(' ')

    dictionary = {}
    fo = open('filename.csv')
    data = csv.reader(fo)
    for row in data:
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
    fo.close()
    ret = []
    for i in abbrv:
        try:
            ret.append(dictionary[i])
        except KeyError:
            ret.append(i)
    return ret
def main():
    user = input("abbreviations")       
    print(CreateDictionary(user))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The csv library has a DictReader object you can use to automate the process.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader